# heartbeat/autowakup a vm instance in a scaleset

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

need to deploy a workload in the vm as iaas, issue is the legacy workload wont work in a cluster multi-instance environment, so can only have one instance in the entire vm scaleset. is there a way to heartbeat the vmss so that if the vm instance is down or service crashed, wake up another replica to start taking the load. Is this setting in the vmss level or at the load balancer level? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use either [Application Health extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-health-extension) or [Load balancer health probes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-custom-probe-overview) to enable application health monitoring for instances. Only one of these can be enabled at a time. As the extension reports health from within a VM, the extension can be used in situations where external probes such as Application Health Probes (that utilize custom Azure Load Balancer probes) can’t be used.

You also could perform instance repairs using [automatic instance repairs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-automatic-instance-repairs). After the automatic repairs policy is enabled, when an instance is found to be unhealthy, the scale set will automatically delete the unhealthy instance and create a new one to replace it.

In my opinion, if there is no load balancer mechanism in front of your VMSS, you can directly deploy the Application Health extension on your VMSS instances, otherwise, you prefer to use the load balancer health probe to monitor your backend endpoint health.